# Ubuntu 15.10 Drivers for Linksys Cisco WUSB54GSC Wi-Fi Dongle

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, internet

I just barley got Ubuntu. SO I'm moving my computer to a different room that I can't connect my Ethernet cord through. So I am trying to use an old Wi-Fi dongle I had to connect. But it seems that there is no drivers for this thing.

It looks like this.

http://cache-www.linksys.com/support/images/KB4395-001_EN.png
I don't have enough rep yet to add the image.

And I heard that Ciso/Lnksys is not supporting linux.

I can't seem to find drivers for this dongle maybe I could get some help or what? Or am I screwed and this is only for windows?

Comment: Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lsusb` Edit your question to add the result relevant to the Linksys wireless.

Comment: @chili555 The title? or what?

Comment: The entire line. We especially require the usb.id; numbers in the form of `(1234:5678)` or somesuch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long awaited email from lynksys they do not in any way support or make drivers for any linux operating systems.